# How to pass ID into controller and display it on a modal with the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Datatable which is populated by the controller: 
[image]

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    vm = new RIROViewModel();
    vm.RIROUsers = new List<ResourceViewModel>();

    foreach (var user in db_RIRO.sp_GetAllRIRORoster())
    {
        vm.RIROUsers.Add(new ResourceViewModel()
        {
            EID = user.EID,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            EmployeeType = user.EmployeeType,
            ProjectName = user.ProjectName,
            JobTitle = user.JobTitle,
            Level = user.CareerLevel,
            ACNRollOn = user.HireDate,
            ManagerName = user.Manager,
            LeadName = user.Supervisor,
            UserID = user.UserID,
            RollTypeValue = user.RollTypeValue
        });
    }
    return View(vm);
}
```

**View**

```
@model OnlineRIRO.ViewModel.RIROViewModel

@foreach (var user in Model.RIROUsers)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">@(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@user.EID</td>
        <td class="text-center">@user.ACNRollOn</td>
        <td class="text-center">@(user.Level + " - " + user.JobTitle)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@user.EmployeeType</td>
        <td class="text-center">Sample</td>
        <td class="text-center">@user.LeadName</td>
        <td class="text-center">@user.ManagerName</td>
        <td class="text-center">@user.RollTypeValue</td>
        <td class="text-center">***</td>
        <td class="text-center">***</td>
        <td class="text-center">***</td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("GetDetails", "RIRO", new { id = user.UserID })"
               class="btn btn-xs btn-primary details" data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#exampleModal1" data-id="@user.UserID">View Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Now when I click the `View Details` button I want the details of the selected item to display on the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                        <label for="">* EID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="">

                        <label for="">* Lead Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="">

                        <label for="">* Manager Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the code I've tried:

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int id)
{
    sp_GetUserDetails_Result result = db_RIRO.sp_GetUserDetails(id).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewData["EID"] = result.EID;

    return View(result);
}
```

I am using the stored procedure `sp_GetUserDetails` which accepts one parameter of `id`. How do I pass the results of the stored procedure to a modal on the same view?

Answer (score 0):

Create your Modal as a partial view.
Change your a tag element to make a javascript post instead.
Pass the @userId variable as a parameter in your post request.
Populate the modal with the data in your controller.
Return the partial view.
Insert the partial view into a container.
Show the container as a modal.

[Controller]

```
public ActionResult GetModalPartialView(long UserId){
 //map your db result to a view model.
 var model = db_RIRO.sp_GetUserDetails(id).FirstOrDefault();
 //return your view
 return view("~/Views/Shared/_Modal.cshtml",model);
}
```

[Html]

```
<a href="#" onclick="getDataAndShowView(@UserId)">View Modal</a>
<div id="modal-container" style=display:none;></div>
```

[Javascript]

```
function getDataAndShowView(UserId){
 var data = {
   UserId : UserId;
 };
 $.post("@Url.Action("GetModalPartialView","Controller")",data,function(resp){
    $("#modal-container").html(resp);
    $("#modal-container").modal("show");
 });
}
```

Comment: The `@Url.Action` doesn't seem to work. When I check the console it only prints the url along with the `@Url.Action`